# Wrong files compiled in a C++ program using Dev-C++5.11

Tags: c++, windows-10, dev-c++

I want to ask something that might sound stupid but I dont know how to get over it.

I wrote a C++ program with some header files and 2 cpp files, one of which includes main.In the header files there are the definitions of some classes I created that have some inline functions and some functions that I declared in the classes and defined in one of the cpp files (not the one with main).
The program compiled and run fine but I wanted to change a few details in some of the inline functions of the classes. I did those changes and the program compiled and ran BUT it was using the previous version of the header files and not the new one.

I have tried creating a new project using the new files but even then the program will actually use their old version.

I am using Dec-C++5.11 in windows 10.

Solved. Looks like I needed to change the file name. Thank you very much!!

Comment: did you make 'clean' between builds? as for the new project I would guess that somehow you are still including the old files. change the header names and try again. that might help identify the issue. or add -H to the compile line which will show (on many compilers) the header files that are getting pulled in.

Comment: Changing name worked! Thank you very much!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Some build systems will only perform "incremental" builds, so if you change a source file then that source file is recompiled, but unless you rebuild the whole project your original header content may still be used. This is even more so the case if you are using precompiled headers, and it may also affect inline functions in that their content has already been "inlined" into source files for whom a rebuild is not being triggered.

Changing the header's filename will work around this "cache" in many cases, but the correct (and far more user-friendly) approach is to ensure that you instruct your IDE to rebuild the entire project from scratch. In Dev-C++, that option is called "**Rebuild All**". I would generally recommend this option whenever you alter a header file.

(If you were using GNU Makefiles, you would perform `make clean` before your next `make all`).